# Access synced Exchange calendar from desktop browser

Tags: nexus-one, calendar, sync, 2.2-froyo

I know this is a bit tangential, but bear with me. 
The Exchange calendar sync works perfectly for me, however, it would be AWESOME if I could see my exchange calendar with my other Google calendars in the desktop browser, just like it does on my phone. :) It looks like the Exchange Sync uses Google Calendar to merge both my personal Google calendar and my business exchange calendar on the phone.

Any way to recreate this on the desktop browser and see all my calendars together? I have a rooted Nexus One running the stock Froyo 2.2 rom.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Outlook 2007, you can use the built-in Publish My Calendar feature to publish it to Microsoft servers, which will make the ICS feed available to add as a calendar in Google Calendar.

In Outlook 2007, go to the Calendar section and click the "Publish My Calendar..." link. Fill out that dialog and it will start syncing.

If necessary, feel free to adjust which calendars are shown in your Android device via the Calendar app's Option menu item "Calendars".

Comment: This is a good idea, but I'm trying to avoid setting up another sync, especially one that is reliant on my desktop app running. It seems like the built-in sync is using a Google Calendar, but maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that's synced to your Google Calendar on your phone should also be on your Google Calendar on the net (https://www.google.com/calendar).  You can have multiple calendars in Google Calendar, perhaps the calendar you're phone is syncing to isn't set to be visible in the web view?

Answer (score 0):

My workplace has Exchange email and I've managed to have it sync with my Google account and NOT use my main Google calendar, with relatively little work.

I have the following setup:

- Me@google personal Google account
- Me@work Exchange account
- Me@work Google account (go to Google, *Sign Up* for new account, use Me@work as "existing email address") that is separate from my main Google account
- [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=98563) on my work computer linking to my Me@work Google account
- Me@work Google calendar shared with my Me@google Google calendar

It does have the downside of needing the a computer to be active (no easy way around that that I know of) but it has the upside that it partitions my work events into a separate calendar and integrates tightly into my heavy personal Google use.

There IS a .NET application that someone wrote that lives as a service on a Windows server and periodically does the sync itself.  But I can't seem to find it now, and it does require you to have a Windows server you'd be allowed to run it on.  And if you have to leave a Windows machine running anyway, you could just put Outlook on it and use Google Calendar Sync.

If you had admin rights on the Exchange server, this might also be an option: http://code.google.com/p/google-calendar-connectors/wiki/Overview