# Push Android Exchange Calendar to Google Web Calendar

Tags: sync, calendar, exchange, vpn, google-calendar

Let me start off by saying this question is essentially an updated version of [Access synced Exchange calendar from desktop browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/access-synced-exchange-calendar-from-desktop-browser) but not a duplication

I have a work phone with Exchange access over VPN, let's called it me@work.  This syncs to an Android phone running the VPN tool but uses my personal Google account me@home.  I don't want or need to carry the work phone around during non-business hours, but it's great to know "oh I have a meeting tomorrow morning" or when making personal plans to know what my schedule is like without having to say "Let me check my work phone later to make sure I'm available"

me@work uses the Google native calendar app on Android.  I don't currently sync my personal calendar to my work phone, but me@home is the main Google Account on that phone.  Is there anyway to publish/sync those appointments to https://calendar.google.com/calendar with an app on Android?  This would enable the events to show up on the webpage, and since they're syncing with my personal Google account they would likewise show up in my personal phone.

As bonus points, is there a way to have this be a one-way or isolated sync, so my work calendar doesn't show personal events?

My company's Exchange server is only available over VPN, so I can't just sync directly to my personal phone.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit late but maybe there is a solution now: Someone else had the same problem and asked me for a solution. I have created an Android app for this purpose now. It can copy/sync a calendar (e.g. your Exchange calendar) into another calendar (e.g. a new Google calendar that you create in your me@home Google account). This way you can see your work events in your me@home Google account but your personal events won't appear in your me@work work account.

It is a one way sync from your Exchange account into your Google account:

*Exchange (me@work) -> Android calendar -> [SyncCal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calengoo.synccal) -> Android calendar -> Google (me@google)*

You can find the app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calengoo.synccal

It can be used for free but it also contains an In-App purchase for an automatic sync.

Answer (score -2):

I used an app call e.sync from the Google play store and it works great. All of my work calendar events syncs to my Google calendar which shows up on my personal phone

Comment: Can you link this app?

Comment: You should mention the full name of the app: [Exchange Calendar Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.mp.calendar.sync)